# Как отобразить CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton целиком (а не пиктограммой) в вертикально закрепленной CMFCToolBar

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Вообще, это клон [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67038585/how-to-show-the-whole-cmfctoolbarcomboboxbutton-not-an-icon-in-cmfctoolbar-doc) на stackoverflow.com. (Просто там никто не отвечает).

Есть MFC-приложение (где класс приложения является наследником от `CWinApp`), и в этом приложении есть класс, порожденный от `CToolBar`. Когда такая панель прикрепляется слева или справа, то в ней все равно целиком (а не пиктограммой) отображается комбобокс.

[image]

Такое поведение возможно благодаря следующему коду:

```cpp
class CMyToolBar : public CToolBar
{
public:
    CMyToolBar();

protected:
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg void OnMove(int x, int y);
    afx_msg LONG OnCheckUpdate(UINT uParam, LONG lParam);
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

const int COMBOBOX_POS = 8;
const int COMBOBOX_WIDTH = 180;

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyToolBar, CToolBar)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_MOVE()
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_USER + 3, OnCheckUpdate)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

CMyToolBar::CMyToolBar() {}

void CMyToolBar::OnPaint()
{
    Default();

    CMainFrame* pMainFrame = dynamic_cast<CMainFrame*>(AfxGetMainWnd());
    if (pMainFrame != NULL && ::IsWindow(pMainFrame->m_comboBox.m_hWnd))
    {
        PostMessage(WM_USER + 3, 0);
    }
}

LONG CMyToolBar::OnCheckUpdate(UINT uParam, LONG lParam)
{
    CMainFrame* pMainFrame = dynamic_cast<CMainFrame*>(AfxGetMainWnd());

    if (pMainFrame != NULL && ::IsWindow(pMainFrame->m_comboBox.m_hWnd))
    {
        CRect toolBarRect, comboBoxRect;
        GetClientRect(&toolBarRect);
        GetItemRect(COMBOBOX_POS, &comboBoxRect);

        bool bChanged = false;
        if (toolBarRect.Height() > comboBoxRect.Height() * 2)
        {
            if (comboBoxRect.Width() != COMBOBOX_WIDTH)
            {
                SetButtonInfo(COMBOBOX_POS, ID_COMBOBOX, TBBS_SEPARATOR, COMBOBOX_WIDTH);

                CalcDynamicLayout(0, LM_HORZ | LM_MRUWIDTH | LM_COMMIT);
                bChanged = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (comboBoxRect.Width() != COMBOBOX_WIDTH)
            {
                SetButtonInfo(COMBOBOX_POS, ID_COMBOBOX, TBBS_SEPARATOR, COMBOBOX_WIDTH);
                CalcDynamicLayout(0, LM_HORZ | LM_HORZDOCK | LM_COMMIT);
                bChanged = true;
            }
        }

        if (bChanged || uParam == 1)
        {
            CRect newComboBoxRect;
            GetItemRect(COMBOBOX_POS, &newComboBoxRect);
            pMainFrame->m_comboBox.MoveWindow(newComboBoxRect, FALSE);
            pMainFrame->ShowControlBar(this, FALSE, FALSE);
            pMainFrame->ShowControlBar(this, TRUE, FALSE);
        }
    }

    return 0L;
}

void CMyToolBar::OnMove(int x, int y)
{
    CToolBar::OnMove(x, y);

    CMainFrame* pMainFrame = (CMainFrame*)AfxGetMainWnd();

    if (pMainFrame != NULL && ::IsWindow(pMainFrame->m_comboBox.m_hWnd))
    {
        PostMessage(WM_USER + 3, 1);
    }
}
```

Именно такое поведение для комбобокса нужно реализовать в MFC-приложении с классом приложения *CWinAppEx*.

Все попытки реализовать такой код с классом-наследником от *CMFCToolBar* не работают. (Было создано MFC-приложение с классом приложения *CWinAppEx*, был переопределен метод *OnResetToolBar*, в классе-наследнике от *MFCToolBar* были переопределены методы *OnPaint*, *OnMove*, *CheckUpdate* (с попытками вызова *CalcFixedLayout()*, *AdjustSize()* и т.д.), но ничего не работает).

*Как нужно реализовать класс-наследник от CMFCToolBar чтобы достичь требуемого поведения? (Или, возможно, нужно по-другому добиваться требуемого поведения?)*

---

| Среда |  |
| --- | --- |
| OS | Windows 10 x64 |
| Visual Studio | Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 (Version 16.8.3) |
| Windows SDK version | 10.0 |
| Platform toolset | Visual Studio 2019 (v142) |

Ниже приведены ссылки с проектами (и с описаниями, как создать проекты с нуля):
[Проект с CToolBar](https://github.com/ordinary-developer/CToolBarPrj.git)
[Проект с CMFCToolBar](https://github.com/ordinary-developer/CMFCToolBarPrj.git)

**P.S.**
Нижеуказанные ссылки - это не то, что мне нужно.

[MFC: How do you get CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton to show on a CMFCToolBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62334917/mfc-how-do-you-get-cmfctoolbarcomboboxbutton-to-show-on-a-cmfctoolbar)

[How to SetOriginalState of a dynamically created CMFCToolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52294485/how-to-setoriginalstate-of-a-dynamically-created-cmfctoolbar)

[How to SetOriginalState of a dynamically created CMFCToolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52294485/how-to-setoriginalstate-of-a-dynamically-created-cmfctoolbar)

[Adding a check combobox to an CMFCToolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36556027/adding-a-check-combobox-to-an-cmfctoolbar)

[How to make CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton able to works in vertical mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160372/how-to-make-cmfctoolbarcomboboxbutton-able-to-works-in-vertical-mode)

[How to change CMFCToolBar runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588238/how-to-change-cmfctoolbar-runtime)

[CMFCStatusBar change height when the icon is added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137299/cmfcstatusbar-change-height-when-the-icon-is-added)

[How to change CComboBox edit control's height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684897/how-to-change-ccombobox-edit-controls-height)

[How to set size and Transparent / Clear CMFCToolBar Button and Icon in mfc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52251885/how-to-set-size-and-transparent-clear-cmfctoolbar-button-and-icon-in-mfc)

[CMFCToolBar & CMFCMenuBar don't show dynamic items by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21849438/cmfctoolbar-cmfcmenubar-dont-show-dynamic-items-by-default)

[CMFCToolBarDateTimeCtrl - appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985982/cmfctoolbardatetimectrl-appearance)

[How to add custom control in MFCtoolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54127436/how-to-add-custom-control-in-mfctoolbar)

[How to change button position in CMFCToolBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32221408/how-to-change-button-position-in-cmfctoolbar)